# How to make a variable of an Ajax GET request to retrieve JSON data?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, getjson

I did some reading about 'asynchronise ajax json calls' and I also watched some tutorials on youtube. After that I came up with the code below to return the response of the getJSON call in a global variable called `fieldList`. But the objects in my `var fieldList` stay empty. I think it is due to the asynchronise call being completed, after filling `var fieldList`. But I'm lost on how to solve this at the moment. So can anyone help me with my code?

My .js file:

```
  var fieldList = $("div.slctField");  

    $("#slctTable").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_fields.php?table=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
            var options = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }
        $("#slctField").html("");
        $("#slctField").append(options);
        $("#slctField").change();
    });    
    });

console.log(fieldList);
```

This is what I'm getting back at the moment(an empty object):
[image]

I checked what's in my select list now and first i tryed to get the options out of the list and that worked. I got the following output:

[image]

And when i check what was in the options i got the values like this:

[image]

But when i tryed to get all the values out of the dropdown with this code:

```
var values = $("select#slctAttribute option").map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get(); 

console.log(values);
```

I got this back in my console:

[image]

So it's still empty but I don't know why?

Comment: Putting `fieldList = $("div.slctField"); ` at the end of the `getJSON` function may help if what I'm guessing is what you want.

Comment: I added `fieldList = $("div.slctField");` right after  `$("#slctField").change();` but my global ` var $fieldList` still had no objects in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yeah Juhana i did read up on that question. But I'm still not getting what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Yeah it is. Because if someone could tell me what's wrong with my code, I could understand what i did wrong.

Comment: @L.Grunn No, `console.log` it right there, after `$("#slctField").change();` not outside the function.

Comment: Yeah that works. Now i am getting back the objects. But now the global `var fieldList` is undefined.

Comment: @L.Grunn Too many comments, added an answer. Do read the answers to the question linked in the comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the code that you have written.

On `$("#slctTable").change()`, the `$.getJSON` is executed.

`$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function which means that the ajax request is sent and the `success` callback function that you have specified will be executed only after the ajax completes successfully.

```
    var fieldList = $("div.slctField");  

    $("#slctTable").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_fields.php?table=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
            var options = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }
        $("#slctField").html("");
        $("#slctField").append(options);
        $("#slctField").change();
    });    
    });

console.log(fieldList);
```

This means that the statements after `$.getJSON` will continue executing. Thus, when you reach `console.log(fieldList);`, the ajax may not have completed. So the content of $("#slctField") may not have been set.

If you `console.log` inside the success callback, `console.log` will report the value properly because it is executed only after the ajax request is successful.

The following will show the value properly.

```
    var fieldList = $("div.slctField");  

    $("#slctTable").change(function()
    {
        $.getJSON("dropdown_code/get_fields.php?table=" + $(this).val(), success = function(data)
        {
            var options = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
            }
        $("#slctField").html("");
        $("#slctField").append(options);
        $("#slctField").change();
        console.log(fieldList);
    });    
    });
```

EDIT: 
Consider the following demo.

I have used an `ajax` request to load some results from Wikipedia and put it in your dropdown as options. Don't bother about the URL.

Click on the `getOptions` button. Compare the contrast values of `console.log` 1 - outside the success callback and `console.log` 2 - inside and at the end of the success callback.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var fieldList = $("#slctField");

  $("#selectButton").click(function() {
    var query_url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=search&gsrnamespace=0&gsrlimit=10&prop=pageimages|extracts&pilimit=max&exintro&explaintext&exsentences=1&exlimit=max";
    var search_txt = "ball";
    query_url += "&gsrsearch=" + search_txt;
    query_url += "&callback=?"

    $.getJSON(query_url, function(json) {
      var options = "";
      var data = json["query"]["pages"];
      //console.log(data);
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        //console.log("console.log result: " + data["extract"]);
        options += "<option value='" + v["extract"] + "'>" + v["extract"] + "</option>";
      });

      $("#slctField").html("");
      $("#slctField").append(options);
      console.log("Console.log 1: Fieldlist " + fieldList.children().first().val());
    });
  });
  console.log("Console.log 2: Fieldlist " + fieldList.children().first().val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="slctField" class="slctField">
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Get Options" id="selectButton">
</div>
```

Comment: Owww, now i understand! Thanks a lot for the info Chintan. But when i check the `console.log(fieldList)` it still has 0 objects in it.

Comment: @L.Grunn The first or the second ?

Comment: The second one. It has 0 objects.

Comment: Will have to look into the html if that is so. Check if there is anything in `"div.slctField"`

Comment: Thanks i will do that.

Comment: I checked, and I'm getting back the options, but not the values if i try this code: `var values = $("select#slctField option").map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get(); 
console.log(values);` I still get no value's back.

Comment: Added a demo. Hope it clears your doubts - kindly accept the answer if it does. It may help others too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112614/discussion-between-chintan-and-l-grunn).